# What if I want a single linear regression model rather than an "mlm"?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, mlm

I have shared the top 9 rows of the data I am working on in the image below (`y0` to `y6` are outputs, rest are inputs):

[image]

My objective is to get fitted output data for `y0` to `y6`.

I tried `lm` function in R using the commands:

```
lm1 <- lm(cbind(y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6) ~ tt + tcb + s + l + b, data = table3)
summary(lm1)
```

And it has returned 7 sets of coefficients like "Response `y0`", "Response `y1`", etc.

What I really want is just 1 set of coefficients which can predict values for outputs `y0` to `y6`.

Could you please help in this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
Basically, I want to frame an equation like:
Y = a + (tt x coefficient1) + (s x coefficient2) + (l x coefficient3) + (b x coefficient4)
where;
a is the intercept.
and
Y corresponds to the fitted values for y0, y1 till y6.
So my requirement is to have the same model coefficients for all the 7 outputs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am indeed new to the world of Statistics and Modelling! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `cbind(y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6)` we fit 7 independent models (which is be a better idea).

For what you are looking for, stack your `y*` variables, replicate other independent variables and do a single regression.

```
Y <- c(y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6)
tt. <- rep(tt, times = 7)
tcb. <- rep(tcb, times = 7)
s. <- rep(s, times = 7)
l. <- rep(l, times = 7)
b. <- rep(b, times = 7)

fit <- lm(Y ~ tt. + tcb. + s. + l. + b.)
```

Predicted values for `y*` are

```
matrix(fitted(fit), ncol = 7)
```

---

**For other readers than OP**

I hereby prepare a tiny reproducible example (with only one covariate `x` and two replicates `y1`, `y2`) to help you digest the issue.

```
set.seed(0)
dat_wide <- data.frame(x = round(runif(4), 2),
                       y1 = round(runif(4), 2),
                       y2 = round(runif(4), 2))
#     x   y1   y2
#1 0.90 0.91 0.66
#2 0.27 0.20 0.63
#3 0.37 0.90 0.06
#4 0.57 0.94 0.21

## The original "mlm"
fit_mlm <- lm(cbind(y1, y2) ~ x, data = dat_wide)
```

Instead of doing `c(y1, y2)` and `rep(x, times = 2)`, I would use the `reshape` function from R base package `stats`, as such operation is essentially a "wide" to "long" dataset reshaping.

```
dat_long <- stats::reshape(dat_wide,  ## wide dataset
                           varying = 2:3,  ## columns 2:3 are replicates
                           v.names = "y",  ## the stacked variable is called "y"
                           direction = "long"  ## reshape to "long" format
                           )
#       x time    y id
#1.1 0.90    1 0.91  1
#2.1 0.27    1 0.20  2
#3.1 0.37    1 0.90  3
#4.1 0.57    1 0.94  4
#1.2 0.90    2 0.66  1
#2.2 0.27    2 0.63  2
#3.2 0.37    2 0.06  3
#4.2 0.57    2 0.21  4
```

Extra variables `time` and `id` are created. The former tells which replicate a case comes from; the latter tells which record that case is within a replicate.

To fit the same model for all replicates, we do

```
fit1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = dat_long)
#(Intercept)            x  
#     0.2578       0.5801  

matrix(fitted(fit1), ncol = 2)  ## there are two replicates
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 0.7798257 0.7798257
#[2,] 0.4143822 0.4143822
#[3,] 0.4723891 0.4723891
#[4,] 0.5884029 0.5884029
```

Don't be surprised that two columns are identical; there is only a single set of regression coefficients for both replicates after all.

If you think carefully, we can do the following instead:

```
dat_wide$ymean <- rowMeans(dat_wide[2:3])  ## average all replicates
fit2 <- lm(ymean ~ x, data = dat_wide)
#(Intercept)            x  
#     0.2578       0.5801
```

and we will get the same **point** estimates. Standard errors and  other summary statistics would differ as two models have different sample size.

```
coef(summary(fit1))
#             Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) 0.2577636  0.2998382 0.8596755 0.4229808
#x           0.5800691  0.5171354 1.1216967 0.3048657

coef(summary(fit2))
#             Estimate Std. Error  t value    Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) 0.2577636 0.01385864 18.59949 0.002878193
#x           0.5800691 0.02390220 24.26844 0.001693604
```

Comment: Thanks.
the following worked to get all outputs in one y. and then lm.
library(reshape2)
dat2<-melt(dat1,id.vars = c('tt','tcb','s','l','b'))
View(dat2)